# Exception when call Contains in Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I pass some params(propertyName and arrayIds) on my service and build Expression tree via reflection. When I use Entity framework all ok. Some days ago I migrate to EF Core and I get an error(Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.)

```
public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, string propertyName,IEnumerable searchValues)
{
            //Get target's T 
var targetType = source.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
    if (targetType == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Should be IEnumerable<T>", "target");

            //Get searchValues's T
            Type searchValuesType;
            if (searchValues.GetType().IsArray)
                searchValuesType = searchValues.GetType().GetElementType();
            else
                searchValuesType = searchValues.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();

            if (searchValuesType == null)
               throw new ArgumentException("Should be IEnumerable<T>", "searchValues");

            //Create a p parameter with the type T of the items in the -> target IEnumerable<T>
            var containsLambdaParameter = Expression.Parameter(targetType, "i");

            //Create a property accessor using the property name -> p.#propertyName#
            var property = Expression.Property(containsLambdaParameter, targetType, propertyName);

            //Create a constant with the -> IEnumerable<T> searchValues
            var searchValuesAsConstant = Expression.Constant(searchValues/*, searchValues.GetType()*/);

            var res = Expression.Convert(property, searchValuesType);

            //Create a method call -> searchValues.Contains(p.Id)
            var containsBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { searchValuesType }, searchValuesAsConstant, res);

            //Create a lambda expression with the parameter p -> p => searchValues.Contains(p.Id)
            var containsLambda = Expression.Lambda(containsBody, containsLambdaParameter);

            return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable), "Where",
                    new Type[] { source.ElementType },
                    source.Expression, containsLambda));

        }
```

Comment: What value is null? there's a lot in that code. Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: Expression generated sucsessful. This error when i call tolist on my querable

Comment: EF Queries aren't run until you use them, so calling `ToList` actually runs the query. Regardless, I'm not much help otherwise, except to suggest refactoring so you don't have to use this reflection method.

Comment: i find problem! if my property nullable i get this error. How in my expression call on my property .VALUE?